# Obtaining a list of cities/time zones as used in Apple's Clock app

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, datetime, timezone

I am currently working on an something that contains the ability for a user to do simple time conversions to various time zones based on City, so a user would select a city name and then select the time they wish to convert to the other time zone selected. I am currently using the time zones found in `NSTimeZone`'s database, which I loop through and then create an `NSTimeZone` object using the method `knownTimeZoneNames`. My issue is that this database that NSTimeZone presents to me seems to be different to the one being used by Apple in their clock app. Multiple cities that I can access through Apple's built in app are simply not available to me in when looping through `knownTimeZoneNames`.

I have looked into the tz or zoneinfo database created by IANA but it seems this database is also lacking a number of the places I can see, again, in the Clock app. An example of this would be Geneva, Switzerland.

Does anyone have any idea where this database may have come from? Or is it potentially another database that contains other cities and timezone's that are then matched to the existing database in `NSTimeZone`?

Another thing I'm not sure of is where the country database comes from. In the `NSTimeZone` database you only get the region (Asia, Europe, America, etc.) and the city name, but for example many of the African cities it would be best practise to have the city name and country name - where does this come from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way of obtaining city/timezone data is hack a widget called **World Clock** (for **OS X**), which is developed by Apple, Inc.  Navigate to the big **Library** folder and then to **Widgets**.  Right click on World Clock and open the file named WorldClock.js with a text editor.  This file contains lines of city names and their corresponding timezone names.  That's what I use for my clock application.

Answer (score -1):

You should may be check : [The google Timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/). As it seems that it needs lat, lng, you should first use [the google geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) in order to convert city name to coordinates.